# WordPress / PHP: Check if column has value and then check if value in array

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a table called `wp_invites` which contains a list of names (and other data) for those invited to an event. Below are 4 rows from the table:

| id | handler | lead_name | party | reference | invited_to_reception | reception_list |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Freddy | John | John, Ben, Steven | NgxaIyNybK4O | yes |  |
| 2 | Jason | Peter | Peter, Jamie, Cathy | 6iqIWqdxewf0 | yes | Peter, Cathy |
| 3 | Jason | Mark | Mark | Mx7z9UnCPOQo | yes |  |
| 4 | Jason | Kate | Kate, Louise, Lucy | gumWlKmfmyXg | no |  |

**To explain the above:**

- Only certain groups are invited to the reception (defined by `invited_to_reception`)
- In some instances, only certain members of a `party` are invited to the reception. If `invited_to_reception` is `yes` and that row has no `reception_list` defined, then everyone in the `party` is invited. If `reception_list` has values, then only those members from `party` are invited.
- `reference` is unique identifier which determines which invite to show. For example, `rsvp.com?ref=NgxaIyNybK4O` will show invites for "John, Ben, Steven"

What I'm trying to do is check if the names in `reception_list` are in `party` and if so, show them a checkbox option to ask if they're attending the reception.

**Current methodology:**

```html
<?php

// get reference from URL to determine which invites to show
$reference = ( isset( $_GET['ref'] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_GET['ref'] ) : '';

// check if valid invite (if ref exists in wp_invites table)
$invites_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'invites';
$results = $wpdb->get_results(
  $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $invites_table WHERE reference=%s", $reference), ARRAY_A
);

if($results): 

  foreach ($results as $result):
    $party = $result['party'];
    $party_guests = explode(",", $party);
    $invited_to_reception = $result['invited_to_reception'];
    $reception_list = $result['reception_list'];
    $reception_list = explode(",", $reception_list);
    // $reception_list = (array) $reception_list; // convert to assoc array

    foreach ($party_guests as $index=>$guest):
      $guest_name = trim($guest); 
      
      if ($invited_to_reception == "Yes"):
        if( in_array($guest_name, $reception_list) ): ?>
          Show checkbox options for reception
        <?php endif;
      endif; 

    endforeach

  endforeach;

endif; ?>
```

**Issues with the above:**

- Firstly, for the row with `id` 1, `invited_to_reception` is "yes" meaning everyone in `party` is invited. However, when I access that invite, it does not show the reception checkbox. Naturally this is because I have an `in_array()` check running beforehand, but unsure how I can run both instances (where all are invited and in other cases some are invited) without duplicating the code?
- For the row with `id` 2, only 2 people from `party` are invited to the reception. However, when I access this invite, only one of the names has the reception checkboxes, when it should appear for both of them.

### Edit

Have also tried `array_intersect`:

```html
<?php

// get reference from URL to determine which invites to show
$reference = ( isset( $_GET['ref'] ) ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_GET['ref'] ) : '';

// check if valid invite (if ref exists in wp_invites table)
$invites_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'invites';
$results = $wpdb->get_results(
  $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT * FROM $invites_table WHERE reference=%s", $reference), ARRAY_A
);

if($results):

  foreach ($results as $result):
    $invited_to_reception = $result['invited_to_reception'];
    $reception_list = explode( ',', $result['reception_list'] );
    $party = explode( ',', $result['party'] );

    // if invited to reception and everyone is invited
    if ( 'yes' === strtolower( $result['invited_to_reception'] ) && empty( $result['reception_list'] )){
      $party_guests = $party;
    } else {
      // if invited to reception, but only selected people are invited
      $party_guests = array_intersect( $reception_list, $party );
    }

    foreach ($party_guests as $index=>$guest):
      if ($invited_to_reception == "yes"): ?>
        Show checkbox options for reception
      <?php endif;
    endforeach

  endforeach;

endif; ?>
```

A `var_dump($party_guests)` on row `id` 2 returns `array(1) { [1]=> string(5) " Cathy" }`. It only shows options for Cathy when it should show it for all 3 options who are in `party` and the reception checkbox for Peter and Cathy.

Here is a visual on ***how `id` 2 should appear***:

[image]

Here's how my latest approach is currently working for `id` 2:

[image]

Comment: This looks like you forced everything into one table. Same goes for storing lists in a single field. Maybe think first about normalizing the table.

Comment: To your first issue, I’d think an `or` would solve it. `if($invited_to_reception === "Yes" || in_array($guest_name, $reception_list){}`. Variables might be wrong, but should show the gist.

Comment: Feel free to make verbose and potentially unnecessary variables if it helps with the mental logic. You can optionally clean that up in the future, although they make code self-documenting which is great. For instance, `$everyone_is_invited_to_reception = $invited_to_reception === "Yes";`